# C# - SQL- Are Dynamic array Fields possible?

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access

A little information as to what I am asking and why I need it.
I am writing a bit of lab software in C# with an access database as its data source.  many of my records are straight forward with only one sample used so only one set of data is needed.  others have a dynamic number of samples, all of which need to be recorded.  I would rather not have every record contain space for 30 samples when many will only need 4 or 7. 
I cannot bounce the data down to one set as I need to keep all the raw data.
Making a new record for each individual sample will be annoying for the end user no matter how much automatic field filling I put in it.  I want them to just be able to click new record and put in all of their data.

Which leads me to wonder, is there a way of having something like a dynamic array for the fields?
basically I want to make one record but have  between 1 and say 30 instances of data within that record, and not end up with a table full of zeros for the unused sample slots.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of what you are describing: you should use either a serialized object that's placed in a single column describing which fields are being used or you should change your database engine for a NoSQL structure where each record can have it's own schema, which sounds what you are looking for.